# YouTube v2 API redirector.c.youtube.com

Tags: youtube-api

I have a LG BluRay player which only supports the YouTube v2 API.

Since april Google deprecated the v1 and v2 API and now it can't stream from YouTube anymore.

I'm writing an adapter which answers like the v2 API and does v3 requests. When I've polished everything I'm planning to open source it.

So far everything seems to work but I'd like to know how my BluRay player constructs the following request:

http://redirector.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?id=50a637b1c3c8XXXX&itag=18&source=youtube&uaopt=no-save&upn=fl8QHRXXXXX&el=standard&client=ytapi-BDPLG-BD300-4vioeur9-1&devKey=Ac0m1Poi
JCCq53ZBMox5bokO88HsQjpE1a8d1GxQnGDm&app=youtube_gdata&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1432261781&sparams=id,itag,source,uaopt,upn,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=AE8049D88C106686C1B97E8F9D96F7B96E8XXXXX.3036XXXXX
F7FD63FC380190AB18E4178DC7XXXXX&key=yta2

None of these identifiers are send from my script and I'm sure the bluray player didn't contact youtube.

The Google video identifier for this movie is UKY3scPIMd8 which isn't in the identifiers.

Does someone have access to the documentation for redirector.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?

I'd like to know how I can translate the above URL to a youtube identifier like UKY3scPIMd8 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKY3scPIMd8)

Comment: "I'm sure the bluray player didn't contact youtube." How do you expect the player to get the video in the first place?

Comment: Hi @JAL very sharp comment but my script acts like a proxy and the bluray player only receives data which is filtered by my script. FYI The bluray player doesn't support https streams and I need to strip it to http.